# How to double the items in the cart by updating the quantity in the product cart page?

Tags: module, custom, upgrade, quantity

**Double the value in the cart by updating the quantities.**[image]

Comment: please add clear description

Comment: over the picture there is a button update shopping cart, so when I change the qty, I have to click the button update shopping cart. My requirement is when I put 2 on the quantity input it should be updated by double means 4 items must be added to the cart, just double the amount in the quantity box. Please let me know if its not clear to you.